# How to generate filtered list using reselect redux based on static filtered values?

Tags: redux, reselect

I am fetching news data from an API, in the app I need to show 3 lists. today news, yesterday news, article news.

I think I should use redux reselect. However, all the examples I am visiting has a dynamic filter value (state filter) while I need data to be fileted statically (no state changes these filters)

my state at the moment is

```
{news : [] }
```

How can I generate something like below using reselect

```
{news: [], todayNews:[], yesterdayNews:[], articleNews: []}
```

should I use reselect or I should just filter inside a component? I think reselect is memorized so I prefer to use reselect for performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

```js
const { createSelector } = Reselect;
const state = {
  news: [
    { id: 1, name: 'one' },
    { id: 2, name: 'two' },
    { id: 3, name: 'three' },
  ],
};
const selectNews = (state) => state.news;
const selectOdds = createSelector(selectNews, (news) =>
  news.filter(({ id }) => id % 2 !== 0)
);
const selectEvens = createSelector(selectNews, (news) =>
  news.filter(({ id }) => id % 2 === 0)
);
const selectFilteredNews = createSelector(
  selectNews,
  selectEvens,
  selectOdds,
  (news, even, odd) => ({ news, even, odd })
);
const news = selectFilteredNews(state);
console.log('news:', JSON.stringify(news, undefined, 2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reselect/4.0.0/reselect.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

You use selectors when you need to calculate values based on state such as the total of a list or filtered things from a list. This way you don't need to duplicate the data in your state.