# Redux Reselect not updating when I compose?

Tags: javascript, redux, reselect

I have a Redux Reselect selector that works fine:

```
// in reselect1.js

const getInputs = state => state.inputs;

export default createSelector(
  getInputs,
  inputs => {
    const { thing } = inputs;
    const items = inputs.items
      .map(item => item.text)
      .filter(item => item);
    return {
      thing,
      items
    };
  },
);
```

In another selector it works if I repeat the logic to get the inputs without IDs in `inputsWithoutIds`:

```
// in reselect2.js

const inputsWithoutIds = state => {
  const { thing } = state.inputs;
  const items = state.inputs.items
    .map(item => item.text)
    .filter(item => item);
  return {
    thing,
    items
  };
};

const getSaved = state => state.saved;

export default createSelector(
  getSaved,
  inputsWithoutIds,
  (saved, inputs) => {
    const isSaved = saved.filter(saved => {
      return _isEqual(saved, inputs);
    }).length;
    return {
      isSaved,
    };
  },
);
```

However if I try to reuse my first selector then when `state.inputs.items` changes the new value is not picked up. So the value of `isSaved` doesn't change when it should.

```
// in reselect2.js

import inputsWithoutIds from './reselect1'

const getSaved = state => state.saved;

export default createSelector(
  getSaved,
  inputsWithoutIds,
  (saved, inputs) => {
    const isSaved = saved.filter(saved => {
      return _isEqual(saved, inputs);
    }).length;
    return {
      isSaved,
    };
  },
);
```

I can see in the docs that these functions are composable so Im not sure what I'm doing wrong? https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect

Comment: What is the state, what is the expected output and what is the question (what is not working)?

Comment: @HMR Ive updated my question. Let me know if it's still not clear.

Comment: Not really, sorry. You claim that the selector is not working when you import a function and is working when you define the function in the same file? Maybe you can use the snippet from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62102784/1641941) to reproduce the problem?